# How to correctly bind a DependencyProperty of a UserControl to a property of its own view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

**EDIT: Set the View Model as the `DataContext`**

There are a lot of questions on SO here but they all revolve around doing some funky CodeBehind stuff. What I want is:

I have a view model like this:

```
public class FooViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public Foo Foo {
        get { ...}
        set { ... }
    }    
}
```

And I define this in my UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:FooViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

In my CodeBehind file I defined a DependencyProperty:

```
    public Foo Foo {
        get { return (Foo)GetValue(FooProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Foo.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Foo", typeof(Foo), typeof(FooControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

So I now can bind the `Foo` property when I use the control elsewhere.

The missing link is: **How do I bind the UserControl's `Foo` to the ViewModel's `Foo`?**

Currently, I am using some elaborate event handling in the CodeBehind to synchronize these, but I reckon there must be a way to do this in XAML, or is there not?

Comment: So your view model is not `DataContext` of your control?

Comment: If I make it the `DataContext` how can I then bind it to the dependency property?

Comment: A UserControl should not have its own view model. Instead, it should operate on a view model in the inherited DataContext of its parent control or window.

Comment: So how should I do a self-contained user control? Should I really define everything in codebehind with `DependencyProperties` and do the logic there?

Comment: You haven't told what you want to do with the Foo dependency property, but usually you would bind a control property in the UserControl's XAML to that property. You do that by using a RelativeSource binding, e.g. `<Label Content="{Binding Foo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />`

Comment: When you use your control, you would bind Foo like `<FooControl Foo="{Binding SomeFooViewModelProperty}" />`

Comment: I know both things. I want to bind the `Foo` of the control from outside like in your second comment, and the user control itself should populate several fields from one `Foo` instance. That's why I want to delegate the `Foo` that is pushed in to a private view model that does the calculations, sets some additional properties and these are in turn bound to the controls in my `UserControl`.

Comment: Do you also know that a binding like `<FooControl Foo="{Binding SomeFooViewModelProperty}" />` does not work when you've explicitly set the DataContext of your UserControl?

Comment: The logic you describe should not be in a "local" view model, but in the UserControl's code behind.

Comment: Ah OK, then my "old" approach using only the `DependencyProperty` and doing everything in codebehind actually *WAS* the way it should be done?

Comment: Exactly. Doing everything in the UserControl's code behind doesn't mean you can't use some clever helper classes and if you like call them view model. Just don't set the DataContext, because doing so breaks the Bindings where you use your control.

Comment: "Breaks the bindings" is the entire purpose of the Foo dependency property in the first place, isn't it? Othweriwse you might as well get rid of this property and bind directly to the parent DataContext.

Comment: Oh my lovely downvoter friend also achieved to get this into the negatives. Thank you! I begin to realize why there are so many blog posts out there stating that StackOverflow "sucks"

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that - you can use a style (I'm using your original code when view model was in resources):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    <Style TargetType="local:MyUserControl">
        <Setter Property="Foo"
                Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=Foo}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

However having view model for a `UserControl` is not a good idea. Use dependency properties and bind to them directly from controls inside your `UserControl`. Then when you use `UserControl` - you will be able to bind its dependency properties from outside. However binding them from the inside (to separate view model) is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks for this clarification. As I stated in another comment, what I want to do is: The `Foo` that is pushed into the user control should populate several controls inside the user control. There are some controls whose values "calculate" one value of the `Foo`. For example, a `Nullable<DateTime>` should propagate to two controls: A check box and a control for editing the `DateTime`. If the checkbox is checked, the `DateTime?` should have the value of the other control, if not, it should be `null`.

Comment: Well I agree with Clemens comments on that regard. All in all I think I answered your original question of how to bind dependency property of user control in xaml.